# Effect of PhD advisor name/department on my future

Tags: graduate-school, europe

I am in the first year of my PhD research (in Europe) in Biostatistics and I have a day-to-day supervisor, however he is not a full professor so he cannot be my promotor. Our department head is, but I would technically obtain the PhD at a department of Medicine/Epidemiology instead of (bio)statistics. Would this have a big effect on my future prospects if I wanted to continue in (bio)statistics, or are the topic and connections you build more important? We are considering looking for someone more statistical/mathematical as a promotor or copromotor, would this change much (on top of the influence they would have on the content of the thesis)?

So in short, if the content of the thesis/project is the same, does the name or work area of the promotor have a lot of influence on future prospects?

Comment: Biggest influence is what YOU get known for and then the name of the institution IMHO

Answer (score 17, accepted):

For most people, any such effect is very short lived. It can help you obtain your first job, of course. But after that your reputation is your own and after a while, no one will remember or care who you worked with prior to earning your doctorate.

There are exceptions, however. Some, usually prominent, people maintain long term relationships with their former students and write co-authored papers. They might also have an active visitation program in which people visit one another's institutions to work on things or just give seminars. In a situation like this, it is the group founded by the professor that helps you build your reputation and keeps you connected to the larger work of the group. In such a situation your relationship with the professor moves from student to colleague and can be mutually reinforcing. Working initially with such a person can have long term effects, of course.